# Expiration date from patent EP1228987 & DE60206307

Tags: expiration, fees

I would like to understand the expiration date from patent EP 1228987 and for the DE 60206307
Thank you,

Joaquim

Answer (score 1):

European patents expire **20 years from their filling date**. In your case filling date is 30.01.2002. Interestingly, there is a small discrepancy across the contracting states of the European Patent Office. Some consider the date of filling as being included in the 20-year time span (FR, UK) and some don't (DE) ("What is the term of a European patent?" by M. Snodin, CIPA Journal, July 2016, volume 45(7), p.17). This results in one day difference between the national expiries, I don't think it is important in the majority of cases.

As for DE60206307, the kind code is T2, which means it refers to the *translation of the EP patent* and there is no separate national filling in Germany. The fees of the EP patent have not been payed since 2006, though (https://register.dpma.de/DPMAregister/pat/register?lang=en&AKZ=E020019063) and so the patent has lapsed in Germany.